# How to create a mesh imprint of one object onto another?

Tags: modifiers, 3d-printing

I have a mesh of an ocean wave which I am trying to create as a base for a model ship so I tried using the Boolean modifier to bisect the shape of the ship's hull from the ocean base. It seems to work for a solid cube mesh but for more complex meshes like the ocean wave it does not seem to be bisecting any part of the model. The aim is to 3D print out the base so that the ship fits into the ocean base. The first base on the left is a Benchy Wave not the imprint of the ship I want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the ocean mesh
2. Apply a **Decimate modifier** (to the ocean mesh only) try a **ratio of 0.2** to
   start with.

[image]

3. Retry the **Boolean modifier** using the **Difference** option again.

Comment: If it still doesn't work you can try applying scale and rotation by pressing ctrl+a

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean meshs before applying boolean modifier "UNION"
Clean meshs :
Fiil holes + remesh (under mesh properties ) value 0.1